# object does not support item assignment

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy intentando, colocar cada nombre tomado de una web en una variable, pero que esa variable sea para todos por cada numero i que se va generando en el rango del  `for`, para simplificar el código

Al quitar  `[i]` de  `Users` Me imprime todo bien, pero no puedo guardar cada nombre impreso en la variable para poder usarlo después

```
Users = None

for i in range(1, 10):
   Comerciantes = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
   EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/main/div[5]/div/div[2]/div[' + str(i) + ']/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/a')))
   
   Users[i] = Comerciantes.text
   print(Users[i])
```

Este es el error que me lanza

`'NoneType' object does not support item assignment`

Ya intente cambiar el  `Users = None`   por  `0` y por `"User"`, pero me devuelve

```
'int' object does not support item assignment
'str' object does not support item assignment
```

Comment: El error está claro... ni None, ni 0 ni "User" son listas! Prueba con `Users = []` y luego añade con `Users.append(Comerciantes.text)`. Te recomiendo repasar el uso de colecciones en python, no puedes contruir una casa si no tienes cimientos sólidos.

Comment: Python no tiene arreglos; tiene listas. Los arreglos tiene dimensiones definidas y espacio preasignado. Las listas crecen o se reducen según necesidad y el indice de un elemento dado puede variar con otras inserciones/eliminaciones en la lista.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error es que `Users` nunca fue inicializado (está en `None`), por lo que la operación de indexación en `Users[i]` no tiene sentido.

La forma pythonica de hacer el código es la siguiente:

```
Users = []

for i in range(1, 10):
   Comerciantes = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
   EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/main/div[5]/div/div[2]/div[' + str(i) + ']/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/a')))
   
   Users.append(Comerciantes.text)
   print(Users[-1])
```

En Python no hay arreglos en forma nativa; se usan listas, y lo normal es partir con una lista vacía

```
Users = []
```

y luego ir agregando elementos con `append`.

```
   Users.append(Comerciantes.text)
```

Fijate que no se manejan indices; es una lista y agregas un nuevo usuario al final.

¿Cómo imprimir el último elemento de la lista? Con Python puedes usar indices negativos, que cuentan desde el final de la lista. Entonces

```
   print(Users[-1])
```

con índice -1 es el último elemento, con indice -2, el penúltimo y así sucesivamente.

Finalmente, en Python, como C/C++, Java y otros lenguajes, los indices parten de cero, no de uno: el primer elemento es `Users[0]`.